# clever way to snips some lines from a file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I am trying to figure out how (without a temporary file at all) it's possible to cut, for example, lines 2-10 out of a file.

Basically, I need to remove entries in a CSV that have already been entered but keep the header.

I am sure someone out there is savvy enough for this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ed`, the standard editor:

```
ed -s file.csv < <(printf '%s\n' '2,10d' 'wq')
```

The `< <(printf ...)` will drive `ed` to do the following:

- Delete lines in the range 2–10 with the command `2,10d`
- Save (`w`) and exit (quit `q`) with `wq`.

Your version of `ed` may complain on `wq`; in this case give it 2 separate commands (`w` and then `q`) like so:

```
ed -s file.csv < <(printf '%s\n' '2,10d' 'w' 'q')
```

---

Otherwise, the obligatory `sed` way:

```
sed -i '2,10d' file.csv
```

which is just like the `ed` way, except that `sed` is not really a file editor: this uses (behind the curtains) a temporary file—so it doesn't technically fulfill your requirement.

Comment: On my Debian system, if I run `ed` like you did and check what it does with `strace`, I see it creates a temporary file in `/tmp/` to perform the editing operation.

Comment: @Louis, true, editors _do_ use temporary files `:-D`. Are you saying I lied in this answer? `;-)`.

Comment: Well, I just don't want my dear dear `sed` to not look as good as `ed`. :)

Comment: `sed` and `ed` create a temporary file.

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks for your wonderful input! are you the one who downvoted? `:D`.

Comment: To the raging downvoter: don't stay anonymous! instead, be constructive and explain me why you believe this answer is wrong, needs reworking, or is not useful. I might even learn something from you in the process! You'll see that life will be much better, that stars will shine in the sky and birds will sing in the sun if you adopt a positive attitude. You may even edit this answer if you believe I'm too dumb to fix it myself.